# Flutter - How to use an RGB or HEX value for a Widget Container Color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a container in my app that I would like to use a specific fill color for but i have bee unable to figure it out.  I have no problem specifically using the `Colors.grey[500]` but I would like to use a color that isn't in the Material Color library.  I would really like to use `color: new Color.fromRGBO(200, 150, 150, 1.0)` but this throws an error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to assign an RGB or a HEX value to a widget `color:` attribute?

The error/warning I was getting when I hover over the line of code in Android Studio:

```
The argument type 'Color(...color.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter 'Color(...painting.dart)'
```

Comment: Mind giving us the actual error ?

Comment: Rémi, you actually helped me with your comment!  It's always the small things that cause the issue.  The Error was `The argument type 'Color(...color.dart) can't be assigned to the parameter 'Color(...painting.dart)` - So, I realized that I had included `import 'package:color/color.dart';` - Once I removed that, it worked

Comment: Nice. Consider answering your own question with your answer. And editing your question to include the exception.

Comment: Will do, thanks again!

Comment: Why are you using the `color` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I had made the mistake myself.  I had previously included the color.dart package shown below:

```
import 'package:color/color.dart';
```

It was causing the conflict/error I was receiving.  When I would hover over the error in the Android Studio editor, I would get the warning/error:

```
The argument type 'Color(...color.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter 'Color(...painting.dart)'
```

Once I removed that import, the code I was trying to use worked just fine.